# How do I modularize dropdowns that may be used reused (and multiple on same page) but still be bound to the razor parent page model in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I saw this done on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-8.0 with one dropdown, but I need multiple dropdowns.

```
//Pages/Courses/DepartmentNamePageModel.cs
using ContosoUniversity.Data;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`
using System.Linq;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Pages.Courses
{
    public class DepartmentNamePageModel : PageModel
    {
        public SelectList DepartmentNameSL { get; set; }

        public void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(SchoolContext _context,
            object selectedDepartment = null)
        {
            var departmentsQuery = from d in _context.Departments
                               orderby d.Name // Sort by name.
                               select d;

            DepartmentNameSL = new SelectList(departmentsQuery.AsNoTracking(),
                nameof(Department.DepartmentID),
                nameof(Department.Name),
                selectedDepartment);
        }
    }
}

//Pages/Courses/Create.cshtml.csusing ContosoUniversity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Pages.Courses
{
    public class CreateModel : DepartmentNamePageModel
    {
        private readonly ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext _context;

        public CreateModel(ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(_context);
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Course Course { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var emptyCourse = new Course();

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Course>(
                 emptyCourse,
                 "course",   // Prefix for form value.
                 s => s.CourseID, s => s.DepartmentID, s => s.Title, s => s.Credits))
            {
                 _context.Courses.Add(emptyCourse);
                 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                 return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }

            // Select DepartmentID if TryUpdateModelAsync fails.
            PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(_context, emptyCourse.DepartmentID);
            return Page();
        }
      }
}
```

But I need multiple dropdowns inherited (for instance add a dropdown that can assign normal year of college taken - (freshman, sophomore, junior, senior)), but C# does not allow multiple base class inheritance. Is there a better way to do this than in the example too even if only using one dropdown?

Comment: How about reuse `asp-items="@Model.DepartmentNameSL"` to get  multiple dropdowns ?  What do you mean ' can assign normal year of college ` ? Do you want  Cascade Dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the web, even official sites like Microsoft Learn are littered with terrible examples. Inheritance is not a good solution to the problem they are outlining there, that would be far, far better served by using composition. Using inheritance you'd have a somewhat silly class structure like

```
public class MyPage:PageWithABC 
{}

public abstract class PageWithABC : PageWithAB
{}

public abstract class PageWithAB : PageWithA
{}

public abstract class PageWithA
{}
```

Multiple inheritance is arguably a root of all evil in OO languages as what might look innocent enough:

```
public class MyPage : PageWithA, PageWithB, PageWithC
{}
```

but is fraught with all kinds of problems with resolving ambiguous properties/methods. You can have multiple interface inheritance because at the end of the day there is only one implementation to choose from.

Inheritance forms an "Is A" relationship, vs. composition which forms a "Has A" relationship.  A course relation to department isn't really "Is A Thing-With-A-Department-Name", it "Has A Department Name", or more succinctly it "Has A Department", which is a reference (DepartmentId) represented by a drop-down where you select a Department Name.

Composition can be easily supported in MVC views using partial views for more complex sets of related controls. For something as simple as a Department drop-down, it's overkill. A "pick a department" requirement amounts to loading a collection of `SelectListItem` and populating a `<select>`. That is arguably a really bad example on Microsoft's part.

Now instead if you want to have something like a common Address input, where you can start typing or selecting/autofilling street names, cities, etc. then something like that could warrant creating a Partial View with its own wiring to a supporting controller for asynchronous lookups, validation etc. that can be shared between various screens that "Have An" address. MS is showing an example of what you could do, but like most examples, it's too simple of a scenario to really justify using it.

My advice when starting out is that the most important thing is "Keep It Stupidly Simple". Go with the simplest thing and don't worry about concerns like duplication. Rules like Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY/DNRY) are best served as re-factoring goals. Once you *know* you have something that is duplicated and can be pulled out and shared, then pull it out. Favour composition over inheritance and just keep the "Is A" vs "Has A" in mind when looking at options for re-use. DRY concerns also only apply where repeat concerns are *identical*, not merely similar. Obsessing over unifying seemingly repeated code leads to adding complexity through introducing conditional code to handle exception scenarios within or around base code, or creating inheritance monstrosities like PageWithABC above.